# Unable to login Azure cloud shell with Azure Authenticator App

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-shell, authenticator

Authenticator App works fine to login Azure Portal, but failed to login to shell.azure.com. The App seems to work for cloud shell as it prompted for approval after typing username, but as I approved the login request in the Authenticator App, the web page shown "unable to sign you in" after a few bounces. Login to Azure Cloud Shell is ok with username / password though. Anyone else got it to work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm able to login to Cloud shell with the Authenticator app. Can you try this again with an Incognito/Inprivate window?

Comment: thanks. tried again and with private mode but same result. IE or Chrome same result, the web page bounces back and forth and eventually says "couldn't sign you in".

Comment: Are other modes (pin/password) helping you get in? Are you launching Cloud shell from https://shell.azure.com/bash or from the Azure Portal?

Comment: yes i can use username + password to login cloud shell at shell.azure.com. i'm trying to launch cloud shell directly there (shell.azure.com) with authenticator app, not from Azure Portal. The Authenticator App works perfectly fine to login Portal, and launching cloud shell from there requires no login (which is expected).

Comment: Hmmm, that is strange. Can you include a screenshot of the error in the question? Do you see anything more in the Network calls (F12/Developer Tools)?

Comment: Actually the browser bounces between shell.azure.com and https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=... not able to capture the traffic as it bounces all the way until the message "We couldn't sign you in. Please try again." is displayed.

Comment: Ohk. Some users were able to get rid of such redirect loops in the past by clearing their browser cache/cookies etc. Let me check with our internal teams if this is something they know of. Which region are you operating from?

Comment: Thanks, we are working in Southeast Asia location.